# 2 by 2 Linear Homogenous System with Complex Eigenvalue. Boyce, p409, Question 7.6.4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I don't know how to align multiple equations, hence I post this screenshot. If someone can show me how, thanks.

I think understand everything above the red line, but please inform me about any problms. I don't understand that $(2 + i, 1)^T$ vector in the first line under my red horizontal line? Where's it from?

[image]

Comment: It's not true, it is wrong. Just set $t=0$ and you get $2+i=5$.

Comment: @GitGud thanks. but what were they trying to do? or should i just ignore everything under ther red line?

Comment: At the time you asked this question I actually consulted the book. I have no idea of what the author is trying to do. I would ignore what's below the red line, yes.

Comment: @GitGud thanks you